# How can I maintain a sorted list in my smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, storage

Is it crazy to feel the need to sort solidity arrays?

Imagine implementing a market (double action) you need to sort the orders. I *could* imagine other usecases where sort is useful. But as we all know even a for loop is dangerous in terms of gas exhaustion. What are best practices in this regard?

The search "Solidity Quicksort" returns nearly no results.

I came up with the idea of letting someone sort and upload the data back to the smart contract, then smart contract can just check if the data is right + sorted, which should be much easier than sorting. O(nlogn) versus O(n). The problem here is that the transaction size grows by O(n) now, which, I feel, could be problematic.

Any guidelines, experiences?

Answer (score 5):

The library below provides the ability for your smart contracts to store a sorted list of `uint256`s.

From [BokkyPooBah's Red-Black Binary Search Tree Library](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/BokkyPooBahsRedBlackTreeLibrary):

> A gas-efficient Solidity library using the iterative (rather than recursive) Red-Black binary search tree algorithm to help you maintain a sorted uint key index for your data. Insertions, deletions and searches are in O(log n) time (and ~gas). Note that the key of 0 is prohibited. Use the sorted keys as indices to your mapping tables of data to access your data in sorted order.
>
> Inserting a key into an empty tree costs 68,459 gas. Inserting a key into a tree with 9,999 keys costs 127,210 gas on average. Removing an element from a tree with a single key costs 44,835 gas. Removing a key from a tree with 10,000 keys cost 81,486 gas on average.
>
> An important use-case for this library is to maintain a sorted on-chain order book in decentralised exchange smart contracts, providing a provably fair order matching algorithm.

The library can be found at [BokkyPooBahsRedBlackTreeLibrary.sol](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/BokkyPooBahsRedBlackTreeLibrary/blob/master/contracts/BokkyPooBahsRedBlackTreeLibrary.sol), and an example of the usage can be found at [TestBokkyPooBahsRedBlackTree.sol](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/BokkyPooBahsRedBlackTreeLibrary/blob/master/contracts/TestBokkyPooBahsRedBlackTree.sol).

Following is a chart of the minimum, average and maximum gas cost to insert and remove items randomly (best case) and sequentially into a tree with up to 10,000 items. The x scale is log2.

[image: Chart]

Disclosure: I am the author

Comment: I would like to use this library, but I need to change it a bit (I need signed int). I can see that the license is MIT and so I suppose I can do whatever I want.
I am thinking to rename the library to RedBlack but leave your comments at the header of the class. Is that okay with you?

Comment: @privacyisahumanright.eth Thanks; I just wanted to ask if there is an updated version of this lib for solidity 0.8.0?

Comment: Not yet. Use Etherscan's smart contract search for "rotateLeft" and you can find some recent implementations

Comment: @privacyisahumanright.eth, thanks for the reply; however, it seems 0.6.0 version has no braking changes when compiled with 0.8.3 (I do lose some gas efficiency, but I will fix that later). I wondered if there would be a chance for me to contact you. (I will be using your lib extensively, so I will be creating a battery of tests). Therefore I wanted to contribute in that way. But I do have some additional 5min questions, so I would like to align with you.